# Calculating cosine values for an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, math, numpy, trigonometry

I have this array named `a` of 1242 numbers. I need to get the cosine value for all the numbers in Python.

When I use : `cos_ra = math.cos(a)` I get an error stating:

> TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

How can I solve this problem??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use `numpy.math.cos`, use `numpy.cos`.

Comment: ...because `math.cos` isn't vectorized, but `np.cos` is. (Also, better for performance since only one function call overhead)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is you're using `numpy.math.cos` here, which expects you to pass a scalar. Use `numpy.cos` if you want to apply `cos` to an iterable.

```
In [30]: import numpy as np

In [31]: np.cos(np.array([1, 2, 3]))                                                             
Out[31]: array([ 0.54030231, -0.41614684, -0.9899925 ])
```

**Error:**

```
In [32]: np.math.cos(np.array([1, 2, 3]))                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-8ce0f3c0df04> in <module>()
----> 1 np.math.cos(np.array([1, 2, 3]))

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: my reuptation is only at 11 as I joined stackexachange just now

Comment: @user1469380 [Accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) doesn't require any reputation ;-), but upvoting an answer does.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `math.cos` expect to get a number as argument while you are trying to pass a list.
You need to call `math.cos` on each of the list elements.

Try using [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) :

```
map(math.cos, a)
```

Answer (score 3):

use `numpy`:

```
In [178]: from numpy import *

In [179]: a=range(1242)

In [180]: b=np.cos(a)

In [181]: b
Out[181]: 
array([ 1.        ,  0.54030231, -0.41614684, ...,  0.35068442,
       -0.59855667, -0.99748752])
```

besides, numpy array operations are very fast:

```
In [182]: %timeit b=np.cos(a)  #numpy is the fastest
10000 loops, best of 3: 165 us per loop

In [183]: %timeit cos_ra = [math.cos(i) for i in a]
1000 loops, best of 3: 225 us per loop

In [184]: %timeit map(math.cos, a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 173 us per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy Way Motivated by the answer of zhangxaochen.

```
np.cos(np.arange(start, end, step))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

`math.cos()` can only be called on individual values, not lists.

Another alternative, using list comprehension:

```
cos_ra = [math.cos(i) for i in a]
```