# How to define a one variable function from another multivariable function

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to define a one variable g function from a multivariable function G:

```
def dG(thetaf,psi,gamma) : 
    return 0.35*(cos(psi))**2*(2*sin(3*thetaf/2+2*gamma)+(1+4*sin(gamma)**2)*sin(thetaf/2)-sin(3*thetaf/2))+sin(psi)**2*sin(thetaf/2)

 g = lambda thetaf: dG(thetaf,psi,gamma)
```

unfortunately this is not working and the error i receive is that :

> only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: Related, may be: [Calculating cosine values for an array in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21043644/846892)

Comment: Just to clear it up, are the arguments scalars or arrays?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define some default values. If you do this by using keyword arguments, you don't even need to define a separate function.

```
from numpy import sin, cos, arange

def dG(thetaf,psi=0.5,gamma=1) : 
    return 0.35*(cos(psi))**2*(2*sin(3*thetaf/2+2*gamma)+(1+4*sin(gamma)**2)*sin(thetaf/2)-sin(3*thetaf/2))+sin(psi)**2*sin(thetaf/2)

thetaf = arange(10)
print dG(thetaf)
>>> [ 0.4902  0.1475  0.5077  1.6392  1.757   0.4624 -0.472  -0.2416 -0.2771 -1.3398]
```

You actually can define a separate function, but using keyword defaults is the cleaner alternative.

```
g = lambda tf: dG(tf, 0.5, 1)
g(thetaf)
array([ 0.4902,  0.1475,  0.5077,  1.6392,  1.757 ,  0.4624, -0.472 ,
       -0.2416, -0.2771, -1.3398])
```

Comment: This is not what i want to do, i am defining my function dG, with 3 variables thetaf,psi,gamma, and i would like to find the root of this function, in case :
`gamma = linspace(0, pi/2, nt)` 
`psi = linspace(0, pi/2, np)`

Comment: Here is exactly what i wrote in my script : 
'def dG(thetaf,psi,gamma) : 
    `return 0.35*(cos(psi))**2*(2*sin(3*thetaf/2+2*gamma)+(1+4*sin(gamma)**2)*sin(thetaf/2)-sin(3*thetaf/2))+sin(psi)**2*sin(thetaf/2)`


`nt = 100`
`np = 100`
`gamma = linspace(0, pi/2, nt)`
`psi = linspace(0, pi/2, np)`
`x = zeros((nt, np))`

`for i, theta in enumerate(gamma):`
    `for j, phi in enumerate(psi):`
        `print('i = %d, j = %d') %(i, j)`
        `g = lambda thetaf: dG(thetaf,psi,gamma)`
        `x[i,j] = optimize.brenth(g,-pi/2,pi/2)`

Answer (score 0):

Next time, please include the script in your original question in a nice format.  It makes helping go faster.

I think it is just a simple mistake.  You get theta and phi out of gamma and psi respectively, but then you never use them.  Did you mean to use those as your parameters in g?  If so, then it should look something like this

```
from numpy import sin, cos, arange, linspace, pi, zeros
import scipy.optimize as opt    

def dG(thetaf, psi, gamma):
    return 0.35*(cos(psi))**2*(2*sin(3*thetaf/2+2*gamma)+(1+4*sin(gamma)**2)*sin(thetaf/2)-sin(3*thetaf/2))+sin(psi)**2*sin(thetaf/2)    

nt = 100 
np = 100 
gamma = linspace(0, pi/2, nt) 
psi = linspace(0, pi/2, np) 
x = zeros((nt, np)) 
for i, theta in enumerate(gamma):
    for j, phi in enumerate(psi):
        print('i = %d, j = %d') %(i, j) 
        g = lambda thetaf: dG(thetaf,phi,theta) 
        x[i,j] = opt.brenth(g,-pi/2,pi/2)
```

Comment: Yeah it is my fault, 
Normally it's gammas = linespace and also psi linespace 
gamma in enemurate(gammas), psi in enumerate(psis)
how can i plot the solution x in a 3d plan(gammas,psis) using mplot3d @cc7768

Comment: Well the above is the answer to your original question.  Please upvote and accept.  Start a new question and show what you have tried and I can help.